# Single word for describing some mathematical examples

Tags: terminology

My native language is not English.
Thus I find nowhere other than this site to clarify my doubts.

1. Single word for " Parallel forces having the same direction"
2. Single word for " Parallel forces having opposite direction"

Can I use "antiparallel" for the second one?

or is there another meaning for that?

Comment: Immediate search gives https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiparallel_(mathematics)

Comment: immediate search for "Parallel forces having the same direction" gives https://brainly.in/question/33732146#:~:text=Answer%3A,as%20a%20parallel%20force%20system.&text=Like%20forces%20are%20those%20whose,act%20in%20the%20same%20direction.